# Using Turkish Characters with MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Turkish language has two `i` character, one with dot: `i`, and one without dot: `ı`, the upper case of `i` is `İ`, and the upper case of `ı` is `I`.

MS Access treats `I` as upper case of `i` and this is wrong in Turkish language, for example in indexed field (No Duplicates) if this field contains `I`, Access will prevent adding `i` and allow adding `ı` and this is wrong, the right is to allow adding `i` and prevent adding `ı`.

So my question is How to force Access to use Turkish language for Data comparison.

NOTE: Both Windows and  Office language is not Turkish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the sort order of the database. To do that, change the "New database sort order" to "Turkish" on the "General" tab of the Access Options dialog ...

[image: Options.png]

... and then perform a "Compact and Repair Database" on the existing database to update the sort order.

Comment: Thank YOU Gord, this is what I was looking for.